# How to catch yml parser errors before loading/reloading file

Tags: java, file, yaml

I use the following code below on one of my plugins to create a custom config. Everything works perfectly fine except when the user has a parser error in the yml. For example, if the user missed a quote/space then their whole yml gets replaced with the default yml. I have code written elsewhere that checks to see if they have certain things in their yml file and when not it will add it to the yml file. However, when there is an error inside the file then my "config checker" cannot find the info so it belives it has to rewrite and fix it.

I tried many times to try and catch errors while loading the file but it can't seem to catch any. I was wondering how I could parse the file to check for errors then if there are errors I would turn my "config checker" off.

GUIManager.java <-- java class that creates the yml file

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;

import me.Cmaaxx.AdvancedHelp.Main;

public class GUIManager {
    private Main plugin;
    private FileConfiguration dataConfig = null;
    private File dataConfigFile = null;

    public GUIManager(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        saveDefaultConfig();
    }

    public void reloadConfig() {
        if (this.dataConfigFile == null) {
            this.dataConfigFile = new File(this.plugin.getDataFolder(),
                    "gui.yml");
        }
        this.dataConfig = YamlConfiguration
                .loadConfiguration(this.dataConfigFile);

        InputStream defConfigStream = this.plugin.getResource("gui.yml");
        if (defConfigStream != null) {
            YamlConfiguration defConfig = YamlConfiguration
                    .loadConfiguration(new InputStreamReader(defConfigStream));
            this.dataConfig.setDefaults(defConfig);
        }
    }

    public FileConfiguration getConfig() {
        if (this.dataConfig == null) {
            reloadConfig();
        }
        return this.dataConfig;
    }

    public void saveConfig() {
        if ((this.dataConfig == null) || (this.dataConfigFile == null)) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            getConfig().save(this.dataConfigFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            this.plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not save config to "
                    + this.dataConfigFile, ex);
        }
    }

    public void saveDefaultConfig() {
        if (this.dataConfigFile == null) {
            this.dataConfigFile = new File(this.plugin.getDataFolder(),
                    "gui.yml");
        }
        if (!this.dataConfigFile.exists()) {
            this.plugin.saveResource("gui.yml", false);
        }
    }

}
```

Things i've tried:

```java
try {
     this.dataConfig = YamlConfiguration
                   .loadConfiguration(this.dataConfigFile);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // error found
   return;
}
```

^^ does not catch error even when error is present

Comment: can you include the stacktrace?

Comment: @pedrohreis I could add the stacktrace but it's not very important. I know what causes the error I want to be able to catch the error and paste my own messages with the stacktrace. Basically trying to catch mapping errors inside the yml file during loading.

Comment: you said that your `catch` block is not working and you're capturing a generic exception. Providing the stacktrace would allow us to try to understand where the exception is happening and why the catch is not working.